# HTTPS is not working with TLS enabled in GKE Ingress

Tags: jenkins, https, ssl-certificate, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I have deployed jenkins in GKE using helm, now i am trying to configure DNS for jenkins. I am using cloudflare for DNS and also created TLS secret using my cloudflare certificates. The ingress that i have created works fine for http but HTTPS is not working. Following is my ingress that i used.

```html
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1 # for versions before 1.14 use extensions/v1beta1i
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: jenkins-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-forwarded-headers: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-proxy-protocol: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - jenkins url
    secretName: secret-name
  rules:
    - host: jenkins url
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /jenkins/*
            backend:
              serviceName: jenkins
              servicePort: 80
```

Answer (score 1):

The ingress that you have provided does not specify any service or service port for 443 to serve https requests and only has port 80 which is for http.

To enable HTTPS or gRPC over SSL when connecting to the endpoints of services, you need to add the `nginx.org/ssl-services` annotation to your Ingress resource definition. [1]

[1]https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/ssl-services